# What is the base drop rate of Steam booster packs?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

In terms of booster packs per month, for example. I know that the rate increases depending on the steam level, but the rate increase is meaningless without the base rate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122975/42984

Comment: Funny thing, I'd say this question is indeed a duplicate of that one, but that one was closed for no reason. Maybe let's just keep this one...

Comment: It was closed with a reason. That reason being that it's a duplicate of yet another question.

Comment: The question referred to asks what triggers the drops but doesn't explicitly ask or answer the question of how often you receive a booster

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know there isn't one specified. As people craft badges booster packs are handed out.
You can influence the drop rate by rising your steam level. Every 10 levels you gain increase the drop chance by 20% ([source](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq)).

> How can I get a booster pack?
>   Once you have received all of your card drops, you become eligible for a booster pack, which is a set of 3 trading cards that may include both basic and foil cards. Booster packs are granted randomly to eligible users as more badges are crafted by members of the community. Make sure you log in to Steam each week to maintain eligibility.
>
> Once eligible, your Steam Level increases your rate of receiving a booster pack drop:
>   Level 10: +20% increase in your drop rate
>   Level 20: +40% increase in your drop rate
>   Level 30: +60% increase in your drop rate
>   Level 40: +80% increase in your drop rate
>   Level 50: +100% increase in your drop rate (i.e. the rate has doubled)
>   Etc.